# iOS Application Missing Required Architecture, even when listed

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios5

When building an iOS project inside Xcode 4 for Archiving, the error:

```
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 (-19033)
```

continues to occur. The screenshot below shows the Build Settings. I [have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932532/xcode-4-0-2-archive-build-build-for-distribution-on-app-store-armv6-warning) [all of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-conf) the common fixes, but none of these seem to work.

[image: Xcode Build Settings]

My final thought relates to the first linked question. Does it matter that for "Standard", armv6 isn't listed? If so; how should it be added?

This project is a new Xcode 4 project; only a view controller has been added from the default.

Comment: Same problem here, have you manage to solve this problem yet ?

Comment: @art I haven't revisited it properly since, but recreating the project seemed to work.

Comment: Mine was an old app that got an update, and it throws the same error for iOS Deployment Target < 4.3 as well! So my solution (since I have XCode 4.6 and adding armv6 doesn't help) was to remove all references to armv6 and set this to >=4.3. It worked.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. In your picture, try adding an architecture to the architectures field and name it `armv6`. That solved it for me.

Comment: That works! I guess the next question I'd have is why armv6 armv7 isn't an additional option in there. Eh. Easy enough to adjust! ... wait, spoke too soon, now clang fails with exit code 1 for armv6. Hmm.

Comment: And who said this solutions referres to your xcode version? you don't said what version you have. Instead of downvoting you could edit the answer or add a good comment

Answer (score 8):

**Project** -> **Edit project settings** -> in **Build tab search with "active"** then **unselect Buld active arch only**

**If you uncheck "Build Active Architecture Only", then it will build all the valid architectures.**

Answer (score 5):

On the new Xcode(4.5) for supporting iPhone 5 screen the only method that works for me is to set the target iOS version to 4.3 as minimum (the valid arc should be armv7 and can include also armv7s, but you must delete armv6!), Anything else I've tried including all the answers here didn't help and I got the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem and was very confused because the error that occurred with it said I needed armv6 because I had a deployment target lower than 4.3, but I was sure my deployment target was 4.3.

I have two targets in my project and was looking at the build settings for "all" instead of the individual targets.  Don't' know why, but even though the settings for "all" showed a deployment target of 4.3, the deployment target shown in the individual target build settings were both 4.2.  I changed those for each target and both errors went away.

Answer (score 4):

Remove iphoneossimulator from supported platforms for the distribution/release build configuration. You cannot have that for distribution, it is only for your debug configurations.

Check the image below for distribution configuration (ignore release config).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**My Answer May  help You:**

I had this problem even after following the accepted answer and found the following to work:

In your Info.plist, add an entry for Required Device Capabilities. This should be an array and will have two entries.

```
Item 0 : armv6
Item 1 : armv7
```

It will look like this:

Required device capabilities entry

Answer (score 0):

"**At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7**"

I had this error message, and it didn't make sense to me.

I already *had* **armv7** in the list of architectures for my iPad-only app, and, yes, I did have "*Build Active Architecture Only*" set to No.

But - I also had **armv7s** in the list of architectures.

I removed **armv7s** from the list, and then the error message disappeared.

[image]

Perhaps in XCode 5, Apple will change the message from

*At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7*

to a more accurate

*Only the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7*

I live in hope.